# HTTP/REST based file synchronization

Tags: python, c, http, rest, synchronization

I would like to synchronize folders and files between a server and some client. Due to the fact that the client part is limited by firewalls and proxy server, I'm forced to use a HTTP based solution.

Is there any HTTP/REST based library (both server and client side) optimized for file synchronization?

(Python or C based solutions would be nice.)

PS: the server side has to run on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV)

Python has [some libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539378/python-client-library-for-webdav) to handle it

Comment: But WebDAV has no options for binary diffs and stuff like this, has it?

Answer (score 1):

**Seafile** is a very interesting server and client syncronization software.

http://www.seafile.com/

It's open source and written in Python and C. 
There are many **clients** for different platforms: mobile (Android and iOS), Linux and Windows. 
The **server** part can run both on Linux (also for RaspberryPI) and Windows.

The software is based on the concept of **libraries** that can be shared between users and also crypted both in local and server side.
It uses also a **deduplication** algorithm for bandwidth and performance optimizations.